# Special characters showing up on content retrieved from mysql using php

Tags: php, html, mysql, special-characters

I have content stored in a mysql database. When I am trying to retrieve the content using PHP and display it using html and CSS, some of it displays these special characters ������.

I have declared the encoding type in my HTML, used to render the PHP content as follows.

I have also added this to the head off the html document

```
<head> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <!-- [portable options] -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0;" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

What mistake am I making that the retrieved content shows the special characters?

This is the document that contains the PHP script that retrieves the data from mysql

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">


    <!-- [loading stylesheets] -->    
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />      

    <!-- [loading stylesheets] -->    
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/flexslider.css" />      

    <!-- [loading scripts] -->   

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="blog-post">
                  <div class="wrapper">
                  <!--
                  <iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" width="100%" height="500px" 
   src="debug/includes/news_index.php" name="" id="">
 </iframe>
 -->
         <?php
    // connection string constants
    define('DSN', 'mysql:dbname=mydb;host=localhost');
    define('USER', 'myadmin');
    define('PASSWORD', 'mypwd2015');

    // pdo instance creation
    $pdo = new PDO(DSN, USER, PASSWORD);

    // query preparation
    $stmt = $pdo->query("
        SELECT title, introtext, id, created, created_by, catid
        FROM mytbl_items 
    ");

    // fetching results
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    // if this returns 0 then it means no records are present
    echo count($result) . "\n";

    // the loop should print valid table
    foreach ($result as $index => $row) {
        if ($index == 0) echo '<div>';
        echo <<<HTM

        <span class="post-date">{$row['created']}</span>

        <h2 class="blog-post-title">{$row['title']}</h2>

        <p>
            {$row['introtext']}
        </p>
        <p>
            <a href='read_serverside.php?id={$row['id']}'><input type="button" value="Read More" /></a>
        </p>
        <div class="blog-meta">
            <img src="img/avatar.png" alt="Avatar" />
            <h4 class="blog-meta-author">{$row['created_by']}</h4>
            <span>Category: {$row['catid']}</span>
        </div>
HTM;
        if ($index == (count($result)-1)) echo '</div>';
    }
    ?>
                   </div> <!-- .blog-meta --> 
                </div> <!-- .blog-post #2 --> 

    </body>
</html>
```

What else should I do to avoid the special chars from showing up?

Comment: If you can, stop using **mysql_*** and start **using mysqli_*** or **PDO** instead as it's deprecated, also take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: What text are you retrieving from the database. maybe you could take a look at `htmlentities()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the utf8 charset at the PDO Connection like this:

`$pdo = new PDO(DSN, USER, PASSWORD,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));`

Answer (score 1):

**This works for me.**
Try this one before the start of HTML.
I hope it will also work for you.

```html
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-15'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en-US">
<head>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are characters in your database that does not exist in Unicode UTF 8. The data are not recognized by this format so thew are displayed as weird characters. I suggest you change the `<meta charset="utf-8">` into `@charset 'iso-8859-15'` or to delete the line. If this does not work you have to go to the data that are causing the error and determine the type of encoding that is used.

Answer (score 0):

If you have main or front controller you should put

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

somewhere there. 
If you haven't  put that call at the very beginning of your file before you start output html:

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
......
```